# How to give permissions for specific commands in linux

Tags: linux, terminal

I am new to linux. I have a build.sh file which consists of a lot of mkdir commands and some rm commands. But as I have installed this new in my VB, each time I run the .sh file, it says "Permission Denied for creating directory" and fails.

So is there any way that I grant directory privileges to all users.

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) changes permissions of a filesystem object (e.g. a directory).

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [unix.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add "sudo" in the beginning of the  directory creation command i.e

```
sudo mkdir dir_name
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, I want to remove the permission asking for certain commands like mkdir and grant permission to all users

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the directory in which the mkdir command is being run.
Use the command `ll` or `ls -l` to check the directory permissions.

If your directory doesn't have write privilege for the current user, you can run

```
chmod -R u+w /path/to/directory
```

This might require you to use `sudo` if permission is denied.

If you want to enable it for all users, run

```
chmod -R ugo+w /path/to/directory
```

Alternatively, a quick fix would be to run the build.sh file as root

```
sudo /path/to/build.sh
```

However, this approach is not advised unless you always run it as root